# Why does adding an entry into a table result in the font size changing in a cell that is populated using Xlookup to extract entries from that table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

I created a table that is updated with new entries, thus changing size with each new table entry.  Xlookup is used to pull entries from the table.  The cells where the entries are stored is set to Arial 18pt type, but when the table size changes with a new table entry, the result cell font changes to Arial 10pt.  I have set the whole sheet to Arial 18pt and there are no conditional setting for that cell. I have also set the File>Options default setting to Arial 18pt.  I can find no other settings for default font for the result cells.

Comment: it's quite interesting and un usual too,,,, if possible share the WB so we can examine the issue to fix it,,,, ☺

Comment: I don't know if I get your problem. So are you expecting XLOOKUP to return the formatting of the cell as well as the contents? XLOOKUP only returns a value, no formatting. Or does the font size of the resulting cell change from 18 to 10 pt?